# Add Products button not visible on Classic opportunity page

Tags: opportunity, button, opportunity-lineitem, classic

When you edit an opportunity page layout, you will see these options for the products related list:

[image]

And in the edit page layout this looks like:

[image]

However, when you actually look at an opportunity, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Why is the Add Products button (with an s) not visible? And what could be the difference in functionality between Add Product and Add Products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, They are two different buttons for Classic and Lightning.

- Add Product - It appears in Classic
- Add Products - It appears in Lightning

[image]

Comment: Oh. My. God. "Edit Products" and "Sort Products" are shared between Classic and Lightning, but "Add Product(s)" not. Brilliant! Thanks!